# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {blah blah blah} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied

Tags: wcf, iis, com

I have a WebService written in VS2013 C# that includes an embedded assembly named StatConnectorSrv.  StatConnectorSrv interacts with a third party program called StatConnDCOM to run another program called "R." The service runs on Windows Server 2016 with IIS 10. The service runs fine right up to the point where StatConnector is initialized.  I get the access denied error shown in the question title. A console test program that uses StatConnector runs fine on the server so the issue is getting my webservice code to initiate the StatConnector dll.  I am using 32-bit versions of StatConnDCOM and R.

Enabled 32-bit processes in IIS
Enabled Anonymous Authentication in IIS (set to Specific User - IUSR)
IIS\AppPool\Default Web Site\Advanced\Process Model\Identity: setting to Network Service or ApplicationPoolIdentity does not help.
In Component Services\StatConnectorSrv: Gave IIS Anonymous User full permissions for Launch and Activation and Access Permission

The service reads an XML message with input variables, uses StatConnDCOM to run some calculations through R and then returns an XML message with results. The webservice code cannot get StatConnDCOM intialized  (but StatConnDCOM works fine when I call it using a console program)

Answer (score 0):

The issue, in a nutshell, was that my WCF webservice, running on IIS10, needed to have permission to execute a 32-bit out-of-process server.

**The functional IIS configurations is:**
AppPool\DefaultWebSite must be set to “Classic”;
ISS\Default Web Site\Authentication: Anonymous Authentication is Enabled;

IIS\Application Pools\Default Web Site:
     Managed Pipeline Mode: Classic; 
     Allow 32-bit Applications: True;
     Identity: Local System;

The last bit, "Local System" is what I had wrong